# XSL Transform extracting min and max dates using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I have the repeating structure of XML and I want to use the max() and min() function present in the xslt 2.0 to fetch the maximum and minimum dates.

I am using like max(Detail/Startdate) and it is returning me NaN as the result. Could anyone help me out here?

```
<Info dataSource="source">
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121211</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130112</EndDate>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <StartDate>20121218</StartDate>
    <EndDate>20130114</EndDate>
</Detail>
</Info>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sample you posted and the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="Info">
  <xsl:value-of select="max(Detail/StartDate), max(Detail/EndDate), min(Detail/StartDate), min(Detail/EndDate)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.5 gives me `2.0121218E7 2.0130114E7 2.0121211E7 2.0130112E7` and not `NaN`. Obviously treating those date values as doubles is not the ideal approach so I would suggest to use something alike

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:function name="mf:date" as="xs:date">
  <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(concat(substring($date, 1, 4), '-', substring($date, 5, 2), '-', substring($date, 7)))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="Info">
  <xsl:value-of select="max(Detail/StartDate/mf:date(.)), max(Detail/EndDate/mf:date(.)), min(Detail/StartDate/mf:date(.)), min(Detail/EndDate/mf:date(.))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to convert to `xs:date` first and then to compute a max or min date and not a max or min number.

If you still have problems then post enough information for us to reproduce the problem.